# A challenging problem on sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, problem-solving, collatz-conjecture

Define $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by

$f(n)=3n+1$ if $n$ is odd $f(n)=n/2$ if $n$ is even.Now can we show that for every $x$ in $\mathbb N$ there is $k$ in $\mathbb N$ such that $f^k(x)=1$ where $f^r=f \circ f^{r-1}$ and $f^1=f$.I could verify for some numbers like $6,3,10$ etc that this holds,but in general I could neither prove nor disprove it.I am new in these things,so I do not know much about how to solve such sequence problems.Can someone please provide me with a solution?

Comment: Now that's a refreshingly new problem!  How ever did you think of it?

Comment: @kimchilover I got it in a book.

Comment: If the book has an answer at the back, be sure to let  us know what it is.

Comment: Isn't that the Collatz-conjecture? That's one of the unsolved problems despite a long history of proof attempts

Comment: @kimchilover no answer,it's a problem book.

Comment: @Sudix I do not know if it is a conjecture,I found it in a problem book which belonged to one of my friends.

Comment: Yes, this is the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and is still open.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for the solution of an unsolved problem, namely the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Comment: I don't fault the asker. The first time I encountered the problem was when I was a teenager tutoring a kid who had this problem in his Singapore math school text. It wasn't named nor was its unsolved status revealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found the notorious [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) which was proposed in 1937 and remains unsolved/open. The Wikipedia article (linked above) is good and has many pretty graphs etc.